# webpack путь для index.html

Tags: reactjs, webpack, yarn

У меня вопрос моё приложение имеет такую структуру [image: введите сюда описание изображения] если задеплоить то всё нормально,но стоит мне переместить index.html и он мне в браузере выведет текущую директорию с папками и файлами. И возникает вопрос как webpack ищет index.html и почему именно его. В конфиге вроде нигде не указывается. Вот конфиг

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {

    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Обновленный конфиг

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path : path.resolve(__dirname,"dist")
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /.css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле `index.html` указывается путь до файла `bundle.js`. Если использовать `html-webpack-plugin` этот файл будет создаваться автоматически с добавлением всех путей к css и js файлам.

---

*Дополнительно, рабочий конфиг:*

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Output Management'
        })
    ],
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        compress: true,
        port: 9000
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /.css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: Значит он привязан только по bundle.js ? И там его запускает правильно?

Comment: Да, тэг <script src="/путь_до_bundle.js/bundle.js"></script>, обычно в конце html-файла или в начале с параметром defer.

Comment: А если я захочу переместить index.html,уже нужно использовать плагин html-webpack-plugin ?

Comment: Нет, помещайте куда захотите, только добавьте в html файл тэг <script> с правильным путём до Вашего bundle.js файла.

Comment: так, значит,что-то не так,путь правильный в тэге. Но если переместить напрмер в "src", то отображается в браузере директория корневая, а там если выбрать папку "src",то откроется index.html

Comment: Каким способом Вы открываете сайт в браузере?

Comment: Билдю webpack, запускаю в webpack-sever-dev,приложил выше webpack.cofig

Comment: Попробуйте webpack-dev-server --content-base src/

Comment: Не может найти bundle.js при такой команде

Comment: Добавил конфиг, проверьте.

Comment: ну это с плагином,а если без него,значит в корневой директории нужно держать index.html, верно?

Comment: Нет, я точно знаю, что в create-react-app используется папка public для данного файла. Изучите конфиг create-react-app, но, конечно, проще было бы использовать html-webpack-plugin.

Comment: Я не использовал create-react-app, сам собирал